# Field range index is empty

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I was attempting to troubleshoot why my facets on a field were coming back empty and it appears that my field value lexicon is empty.  `cts:field-values("status")` comes back with an empty sequence.

I know the field is fine because I can do a `cts:field-value-query` as in:

```
fn:count(cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:field-value-query("status", "Active")))
```

which gives me a count of *42248*.  The field has the `field value searches` index option enabled.

For that field, I have a range field index defined with scalar type `string`, collation type `http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1`, range value positions as `false`, and invalid values as `reject`.

But executing any of the following returns an empty sequence:

```
cts:field-value-ranges("status"),
cts:field-values("status")
```

Does anyone have suggestions on troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little surprised you are not getting back an exception. Or maybe that got logged unnoticed?

You need to specify the correct collation when using `cts:field-values` and `cts:field-value-ranges`. So for `cts:field-values` it should be:

```
cts:field-values("status", (), "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1")
```

See also: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:field-values

HTH!

Comment: I tried that, and I still get an empty sequence, no error though.  If I change the collation to the root collation, I do get an error regarding no field range index existing.  But when I call it as you have specified, I still get no values.

Comment: Which version are you using exactly? Can you upgrade to latest patch release to make sure it's not a bug that got fixed?

Comment: I am on 8.0-5.2.  So I went and I switched the collation from the admin ui to the `Root Collation`, and then tested `cts:field-values`, it works.  Then I switched it back to the collation I had, and it still seemed to work.  Then I went and did a reindex on the whole content db, and now those range indexes again have no values.  So it seems like maybe there is something that the admin UI is doing that isn't getting carried over?  My next test is to switch to the `Root Collation` again, and then try another reindex.

Comment: So, just to add on for the tests that I have done, if I change the collation in admin UI, which triggers a reindex, the value lexicon for the field will have values.  If I then do a reindex on the whole content db, the lexicon will have no values.  It does not matter what collation I have set.  This seems like a bug to me, and I will file it with support.

Comment: ML support has been able to replicate the behavior... currently waiting on next steps.